# Old Sci Fi book I'm trying to refind

Tags: story-identification

The book was written some time in 1980's, and is about a Marine who was the only survivor of a fleet wide space boarding action(humans boarded alien ships), and was reassigned to a science team as he was able to interface with the alien tech to stop self destruct. Said marine throughout the story had flashbacks that elaborated the attack. One main part of the attack was that there was no way to turn back.

Comment: Ships or spaceships?

Comment: It has some similitudes to The Outer Limits'episode [`The Light Brigade`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_Brigade_(The_Outer_Limits))

Comment: Aggressor Six, messed up on some of the details.